# Records of custom objects imported to salesforce have currency code that cannot be updated to the same code as in csv file

Tags: data, update, import, currency

I have already imported a list of records of a custom object to salesforce via data loader. Now the imported records have currency fields in ISO code(THB) that we imported to salesforce. Unfortunately the currency is reflecting as US dollars(USD) value in salesforce after being imported. Other existing records (already there in application) are having the currency field as THB .

I would want to have the currency code in the imported records to be THB instead of USD. Kindly guide the detailed steps.

Regards,
Moyumi